Using rgl's extrude3d() function to make a 3D mesh from polygons in R
I'm trying to make a 3D OBJ file using R. My initial data is a Geopackage with multiple polygons. And I want to 'extrude' each polygon to make them 3d. The extrude amount should be determined by the value of an attribute of these polygons.
I have a geopackage with multiple polygons: Screenshot of data list. I am able to plot this data in 2d. 2d plot of data
Each of these polygons has an attribute called 'POINT...50'. I want to use the value of this attribute to determine the height ( z axis) of each polygon by extruding each polygon, but I can't get it to work. So far I have tried to do it with the extrude3d function.
Here is my initial data . Here is my code so far :
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgl)
library(dplyr)

data <- st_read("data/métropole_de_lyon_LGT_LCI_500m.gpkg")

data|>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()

data |>
  extrude3d()

writeOBJ(data3D, '3d model')


I have also used the rayshader package to create a 3d visualization but the problem it that it rasterizes the data so the OBJ file it outputs is not satisfactory. So i want the same result but only using vector to have a clean 3D mesh. 3D visualisation made with rayshader  The goal is to have a clean mesh like this one: Clean mesh

The extrude3d function works on single polygons described by the x and y coordinates of their vertices.  You'll need to extract a list of these from the data object (which I don't know how to do), then pass the elements of the list to extrude3d.  It doesn't know how to handle "sf" objects.

My geopackage has multiple polygons would do you know how I can call the extrude3d function for each one ?

You should be able to use lapply() or some other similar function to create a list of mesh objects.  You can use shade3d(shapelist3d(thelist)) to plot them all, and writeOBJ to write an OBJ file containing them.

Here's an example of how to do this.  It's probably not the neatest way to use sf, but it seems to work.
library(sf)
library(rgl)
data <- st_read("~/temp/métropole_de_lyon_LGT_LCI_500m.gpkg")

open3d(useNULL = TRUE) # don't need to draw on screen yet

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  thickness <- data[i,]$POINT...50
  if (!is.na(thickness))
    st_geometry(data)[[i]] |>
    as.matrix() |>
    extrude3d(thickness = thickness) |>
    shade3d()
}

writeOBJ("~/temp/test.obj", separateObjects = FALSE)

open3d(useNULL = FALSE) # Now draw the file we saved
readOBJ("~/temp/test.obj") |>
  shade3d(col = "red", alpha = 0.2)

This produces an image like this:

